# How to upload a file to release directory during Capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rake, capistrano3

The Capistrano production.rb file executes 3 tasks

- composer install --no-dev
- mkdir storage
- upload! ".env.production", ".env"

The first 2 are executed, but the upload fails: "No such file or directory".

I was able to scp the file successfully from the command line.

How to copy a file to the current release directory?

```
$ cap --version
Capistrano Version: 3.11.0 (Rake Version: 12.3.1)
$ cap production deploy
...
01 mkdir -p ~/public_html/app/releases/20181122210112
...
composer install --no-dev
...
mkdir storage
...
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: 
   Exception while executing as me@site.com: 
   scp: ~/public_html/app/releases/20181122210112/.env: 
     No such file or directory

DEBUG Uploading .env.production 0.0%
...
$
```

scp the file successfully from the command line:

```
$ scp .env.production me@site.com:~/public_html/app/releases/20181122210112/.env
```

production.rb

```
# use absolute path
set :deploy_to, "/home/user/public_html/app"

namespace :deploy do
    desc  "Install app dependencies with composer"
    after :updated, :build do
        on roles(:web) do
            within release_path do
                execute :composer, "install --no-dev"
                execute :mkdir, "storage"
            end
        end
    end
end

namespace :deploy do
    desc "Copy Env"
    after :finished, :copy do
        on roles(:all) do
            upload! ".env.production", "#{release_path}/.env"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Using the ~/homedir relative path doesn’t work in Capistrano, at least for the upload! method. ~ is a Bash shortcut, not SCP, so SCP can’t find the directory. Absolute path set :deploy_to, "/home/user/public_html/app”  worked around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if your need is to copy your local application.yml to the server, and you are already using capistrano, you can use the [capistrano figaro gem](https://github.com/chouandy/capistrano-figaro-yml), it creates a task to update this file on server. in theory, you could run the task automatically and make this file to be updated. is an old gem, but works like a charm and do the work.